# Adobe Javascript object - List and Create folders within a Portfolio file

Tags: excel, vba, acrobat, acrobat-sdk, adobe-javascript

I'm using Acrobat PRO DC and Excel VBA to automate some interaction with Adobe Portfolio PDF files.

Using the Adobe JSO, is there a way to get a list of existing portfolio subfolders?  Or to create new ones?  I'm able to add an attachment to a folder within a portfolio file using something like:

```
Call jso.importdataobject("<1>subfile.txt", "/F/Development/PermFile/subfile.txt")
```

This will import "subfile.txt" into the first existing folder within the JSO's portfolio file.  However, this code does not work if a folder does not already exist in the portfolio file.  Also hard coding the actual index of the folder (via <1>) seems fairly clumsy.

Existing folders don't seem to be part of what's returned via the dataObjects collection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The JavaScript API does not have access to folder names.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That's disappointing, but succinct, and will save me further time looking for something that doesn't exist.

Comment: You could get a plugin developed that would expose the entire collection dictionary to the Acrobat JavaScript engine that you could then access via the JSO but you'd need a copy of that plugin to be installed on every machine that you intended to do this on.